# How to Get the Decimal symbol

Tags: java, operating-system, decimal, system-properties

in Java, how do I get the decimal-symbol that is set in the system?
I DON'T want to rely on the Locale , since it could be changed regardless of the locale.

haven't seen something in System.getProperties(), but maybe I'm missing something
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would want the output to be? And maybe the context you want to use it in? :)

Comment: an example of what I want to achieve:
String decimalSymbol=System.getProperty("xxx"); 
//xxx is the property I'm looking for
if ((decimalSymbol.equals(",")){
 return "X";
}else {
  return "Y"
}

If there is a mean other then System.getProperty(..) , it could also be applicable

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, please upvote helpful ones and choose an answer that best fits your question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the `DecimalFormatSymbols` class. You said you do not want to rely on `Locale`... Well, you can specify your `Locale` in the initialization on the object. But you don't have to.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols sym = new DecimalFormatSymbols(); //Can specify 'Locale' here

char charDecimal = sym.getDecimalSeparator();

String strDecimal = String.valueOf(charDecimal); //Value becomes '.'
```

Hope that helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use system properties to get default locale and then get the decimal-symbol.
As you don't want to rely on `Locale.getDefault()`.

```
String language = System.getProperty("user.language");
String country = System.getProperty("user.country"); 

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale(language, country));
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char sep=symbols.getDecimalSeparator();
```